# Highmaps - Editing the css of state names on map

Tags: css, highcharts

I am attempted to add new text css to my highmaps map in order to have the state name appear larger and bolder. I've tried making this change using by :

```
chart: {
    style: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '14px',
        color: '#002F65',
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
},
```

Although I do see these set css elements when I inspect the graph, it has no affect on the actual map itself.

My expected outcome to to change the css of the state abbreviations displaying on the map: For example CA, CO, AZ, NV etc..

Here is a link to my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw4o695c/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those names (CA, CO, AZ, NV etc..) are a `dataLabels`, so you need to set those style options inside the dataLabels style options config.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oxz34gj6/

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  formatter: function() {
    return this.point.properties['hc-a2'];
  },
  style: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '14px',
  }
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.dataLabels.style